# Bootable USB stick that runs my program

Tags: scripting, live-usb, bootable

I am developing a Python program and want to create a **bootable USB stick that runs my program**.

Requirements:

1. The USB stick should run Linux, including some standard dependencies (LAN/WLAN access, GUI, possibility to hook up to a [projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projector))
2. I should be able to install dependencies for my program (a database, some python dependencies, etc.)
3. I want to avoid any manual setup: I need a script that generates the USB stick, including my program, any dependencies and needed drivers (ideally, think [docker](https://www.docker.com/))

What is the **easiest** way to achieve this?

---

I have considered creating a [bootable Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) and installing my program and any dependencies manually. This resolves 1-2, but not 3. And it seems non-trivial to automatically customize a bootable Ubuntu...

Comment: I assume it should work if you loop-mount the the iso that you would use for the usb stick, add your program there, umount again and use the adjusted iso to create the usb-stick.

Comment: @Garo thanks for the suggestion. I guess this will not allow me to install my program's dependencies though... This only allows me to copy data onto the usb stick. But maybe I can make this work if there is no good alternative.

Comment: @downvoters: Any tips how I can improve this question?

Comment: @Peter upon mounting the image, you could chroot into it and then install dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using help from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226174/install-ubuntu-to-usb-flash-drives-automatically), I was able to come up with a [Ubuntu-specific solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231516/774965) that works for me:

## 1. Install Ubuntu/Lubuntu on a flash drive

These instructions loosely follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/983692/774965).

(Preparation)

- Create a live USB or DVD.
- Turn off and unplug the computer.
- Unplug all hard drives from your computer.
- Plug the computer back in.
- Disable secure boot and fast boot in UEFI settings (the exact steps for this
  are vendor-specific)

(Run Installer)

- Insert the Live USB or Live DVD.
- Start the computer, the USB/DVD should boot.
- Select Install Ubuntu.
- Insert a new target drive to install Ubuntu.
- Follow the instructions.
- Do not install "third-party software", as it may not work on other machines.
- At "Installation type" select "Something else".
- Select "Continue".
- Select target drive (in my case /dev/sdb)
- Select "New Partition Table" and "Continue".

(EFI partition)

- Click "Free space" and "+".
- "Size": 100 MB
- Select "Primary"
- "Location": "Beginning of this space"
- "Use as": "EFI System Partition"
- Select "OK"

(/ partition)

- Click "free space" and then "+".
- "Size": 7800 MB (or something else)
- Select "Primary"
- "Location": "Beginning of this space"
- "Use as": "Ext4"
- Mount point: "/"
- Select "OK"

(Important)

- Ensure "Device for boot loader installation" points to the root of the flash drive (/dev/sdb in my case).
- Click "Install Now" and "Continue".
- Follow the instructions.
- Wait until install is complete.

(Wrap up)

- Turn off computer and plug in the HDD.

## 2. Save the resulting flash drive

Next, save the resulting image to your machine. I wrote a script that handles
this step.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Saves flash drive partitions to disk
#
# Example Usage:
# ./copy.sh /dev/sde ./images

# enable bash strict mode
# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

##########
# INPUTS #
##########

# Checking inputs
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "USAGE: ./copy.sh DEVICE OUTPUTDIR"
  echo "Available devices:"
  sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL
  exit
fi

# parse inputs
DEVICE=$1
OUTPUTDIR=$2
EFIFILE=$OUTPUTDIR/ubuntu-efi.img
ROOTFILE=$OUTPUTDIR/ubuntu-root.img
PARTITIONFILE=$OUTPUTDIR/partitions.txt

# Display helpful information
echo "Saving device $DEVICE to $OUTPUTDIR:"
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL $DEVICE

# Confirm
read -r -p "Continue? [y/N] " response
if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
    echo "Start copying (this could take a long time)..."
else
    echo "Aborting" >&2
    exit
fi

mkdir -p "$OUTPUTDIR"

########
# SAVE #
########

# record sizes
sudo fdisk -l | grep ${DEVICE} | sed "s#${DEVICE}#/dev/sdX#g" > $PARTITIONFILE

# dd: copy and convert
# if: source disk
# bs: sector size value from fdisk output
# count: last "end" sector from fdisk output incremented by one
# conv=sync,noerror: sync I/O and don't stop in case of errors on the source disk
sudo dd if=${DEVICE}1 conv=sync,noerror of=$EFIFILE
sudo dd if=${DEVICE}2 conv=sync,noerror of=$ROOTFILE
```

## 3. Install to New Drive

Finally, install the saved image to new flash drives. Again, I wrote a script
that handles this step.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Installs Ubuntu/Lubuntu to flash drive
#
# Example Usage:
# ./copy.sh /dev/sde ./images

###########
# HELPERS #
###########

# enable bash strict mode
# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# directory containing this script
BASEDIR="$( dirname "$0")"

# run commands at the end of the script (even on errors)
EXIT=""
function addExit {
    # call the argument before ending the script
    EXIT="$@ ; $EXIT"
    trap "echo 'Final tasks before exit...' ; $EXIT" EXIT HUP TERM INT QUIT
}

##########
# INPUTS #
##########

# Checking inputs
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "USAGE: ./copy.sh DEVICE SOURCEDIR"
  echo "Available devices:"
  sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL
  exit
fi

# parse inputs
DEVICE="$1"
SOURCEDIR="$2"
MNT=/mnt

# Display helpful information
echo "Installing to device $DEVICE:"
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL $DEVICE

# Confirm
read -r -p "Continue? [y/N] " response
if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
    echo "Preparing partitions..."
else
    echo "Aborting" >&2
    exit
fi

# record sizes
PARTITIONFILE="$SOURCEDIR/partitions.txt"
EFISTART=$( cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX1 | awk -F" "  '{ print $2 }')
EFIEND=$(   cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX1 | awk -F" "  '{ print $3 }')
ROOTSTART=$(cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX2 | awk -F" "  '{ print $2 }')
ROOTEND=$(  cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX2 | awk -F" "  '{ print $3 }')

#######################
# COPY TO FLASH DRIVE #
#######################

# umount all paritions of this device
echo "Unmounting all partitions of $DEVICE..."
sudo umount $DEVICE?* || true

# create partition table
sudo wipefs --all $DEVICE
sudo parted $DEVICE mklabel gpt

# efi partition
sudo parted $DEVICE mkpart primary fat32 ${EFISTART}s ${EFIEND}s
sudo parted $DEVICE set 1 boot on
sudo parted $DEVICE set 1 esp on

echo "Start copying efi..."
EFIFILE="$SOURCEDIR/ubuntu-efi.img"
sudo dd if="$EFIFILE" of=${DEVICE}1

# root partition
sudo parted $DEVICE mkpart primary ext4 ${ROOTSTART}s ${ROOTEND}s
# sudo parted $DEVICE name 2 UbuntuUSB

echo "Start copying root (this could take a long time)..."
ROOTFILE="$SOURCEDIR/ubuntu-root.img"
sudo dd if="$ROOTFILE" of=${DEVICE}2

##################
# PREPARE CHROOT #
##################
# prepare running command in root directory of new installation

sudo mount ${DEVICE}2 $MNT
addExit "sudo umount $MNT"

sudo mount ${DEVICE}1 $MNT/boot/efi
addExit "sudo umount $MNT/boot/efi"

for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do
    sudo mount -B $i ${MNT}$i
    addExit "sudo umount ${MNT}$i"
done
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf $MNT/etc/
modprobe efivars

########
# GRUB #
########

# update grub
sudo chroot $MNT grub-install -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi/ --removable ${DEVICE}

#############
# CUSTOMIZE #
#############

# prepare scripts
sudo cp -r "${BASEDIR}/customize" "$MNT/opt/customize"

# install software
sudo chroot $MNT "/opt/customize/software.sh"
```

This script also installs additional custom software, using the following script
in `./customize/software.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# enable bash strict mode
# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

###########
# PREPARE #
###########

# avoid locale issues and in order to import GPG keys
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C

#######
# APT #
#######

apt-get update -y
apt-get clean
apt-get -y autoremove --purge

####################
# INSTALL SOFTWARE #
####################

# -y: auto-confirm
# -qq: quiet installation
apt-get install -y -qq \
    htop \
    gparted \
    build-essential
```

Comment: Current Ubuntus and Debians do not require disabling secure-boot anymore

Answer (score 0):

### This method should work and I think it is rather easy

- Create a **persistent live** drive from an Ubuntu iso file using the tool [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).
- Then install the tools you need and do the tweaks.
- After that you can create an image of that drive.
- Finally clone from the image to other USB drives (that are at least as big as the USB drive with the original system). You can distribute those cloned drives to end users of your system.

  It is also possible to let end users download a compressed version of the image and extract it to their own USB drives. mkusb can do it directly from images compressed with `gzip` (faster) and `xz` (better compression), but it can also be done with other tools, if necessary also in Windows.